# Getting mysql rows with privacy setting

Tags: mysql

I have a `posts` table with user posts which looks something like this:

```
id    userid    post    privacy
1     2        xyz1     1
2     2        xyz2     2
3     3        xyz3     2
...
```

where, `userid` is the poster's id, `privacy` is the privacy setting for the specific post. `privacy` 1 implies it's a public post, while `privacy` 2 implies it is intended only for friends.

I have another table for a user to follow another user: a `follows` table

```
id    userid    followid    friends
1     1         2           1
2     1         3           0
3     2         4           1
...
```

`userid` is a user's id, `followid` is the id of the user that the `userid` is following. `friends` is 1 if these two users are also friends and 0 if they are not.

Without considering the privacy setting, combining these two tables look simple:
`SELECT * FROM posts, follows WHERE (follows.userid = 1 AND follows.followid = posts.userid )`

However, I am struggling to include the privacy factor. Basically what I want to do is: if `privacy = 1`, it doesn't really matter because it's a public post. However, if `privacy = 2` then get rows only if `friends = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I played around and might have solved the problem

```
SELECT *
 FROM posts p
 LEFT JOIN follows f ON (p.user_id = f.followid)
 WHERE (f.user_id = 1 AND (p.privacy = 1 OR (p.privacy = 2 AND f.friends = 1))) 
 ORDER BY p.id
```

Let me know if this is correct.